# Java game programming and Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I want to know what is the better way to develop a game in Java with Swing.

It's a Shoot them up, and now all things are using thread.
For example : all explosion use threads, all shoot use threads, all enemy use threads, all shoot enemy use threads...

So up to now I don't use a main game loop to display element and do the math to move elements.

It would be a better way to use threads only for explosions, and use a sequential method to shoot, ennemy ?

I'm not sure to be very clear in my question.

Thanks

Comment: All update are in the EDT, and I think that this isn't long-running tasks.I think tasks during few second only.

Comment: A *few seconds* is still too long for a UI to remain unresponsive.

Answer (score 3):

In most games it is best to only use a **single thread** ("except when..." yes i know, see below). The fact that sprites all seem to do something simultanously makes every new game programmer think they all need threads, but it is only an illusion.

In that thread you sequentially go through a loop called the "game loop":

- getting input
- updating the game objects
- updating the view

Exceptions: (not for the beginner. a beginner should not even bother) Much later, when your game is done and working, you might realize that when loading additional game data you might want another thread that prefetches the data, you can add that then, adding it earlier is evil early optimization.